# How to shade a single dependency using Gradle shadow plugin?

Tags: gradle, gradle-shadow-plugin

I'm writing a tiny library which uses a couple of dependencies.
One of them is the `org.json` library.

I want to shade only this `org.json` library by including the sources in my own jar and relocating them to another `repackaged` package.

I had a look at the Gradle Shadow plugin but it creates an `-all` jar.
I just want the normal jar and only the `org.json` lib to be relocated.
Is this possible?

Alternative is just copying those classes to my project and checking them in source control.

Comment: from shadow plugin description, you should be able to do anything that the maven shade plugin does, including relocating packages. Does this not help http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/#relocating_packages ?

Comment: Yes I tried that "relocate" option together with the shadowJar task. But then I get only a *-all.jar. I just want a normal my-project.jar with only 1 dependency shaded.

Comment: are the shaded packages included in your my-project.jar? Can I re-interpret your question as: how do I exclude un-relocated dependency packages from the output jar?